# Message/Wall Continuously Pushes Down Webpage Body

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Images attached @ http://imgur.com/a/dn9kU#PCS8Azm

I am trying to create a "side message" that extends in jQuery when you hover over it. The jQuery coding isn't a problem. However, the HTML/CSS positioning is. Note that I'm using Bootstrap's theme for this.

The message is pushing down the image banner and body. See www.mc-tron.com for the website example.

First image: What the normal website looks like.

Second image: What I would like.

Third image: What happens.

So I basically want the side message to overlap over the banner and web page without pushing everything down.

Answer (score 0):

can you use

```
<div style="position:absolute;" class="sidemessage">
```

?

Comment: shouldn't really be a question, it is the way to do it